# CSS and JS load as copies of HTML in website built with gulp and angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, gulp

I'm making a website using gulp and angular. When I load the page in the browser, my developer tools, sources tab shows my css resources to be copies of my html. This only started happening after I tried to make a custom directive using angular. I took the custom directive out and tried to change everything back but it is still loading both my css and js as just the html code from the page. Does anyone have any idea what might cause this? My google and stackoverflow searches have turned up nothing.

Comment: Providing some code would help.

Answer (score 0):

After restarting Chrome and restarting my computer twice everything magically started working again. So I never knew what exactly went wrong but the principles of always try "on/off" before anything else seems to apply.